# Does Critical Strike chance have a cap?

Tags: diablo-iii

In similar way to Dodge, Critical Strike has a certain %X chance to occur. Can I ever reach a 100% critical strike or is there a maximum limit that cannot break? If there is a limit, what is it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Crital Strike Chance has a cap at 100%. Useing some Demon Hunter abilities I was able to get my crit to 100% [image]

Then I used another skill that when equiped with a hand cross bow it should increase it by 10% more, but when it is used it stays at 100% 
[image]

If the cap was any lower than 100% my ability would have stopped at the cap, if it was over 100% I would also been able to reach past 100%.

Comment: It's... not necessarily true that Crit doesn't have a cap below 100% just because you can get to 100% crit. If D3 [*does* use a 1-roll system](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67291/how-do-attacks-work-in-diablo-iii/70138#70138), your displayed crit could reach 100%, but in reality, it would be capped at some lower amount based on mob avoidance. This is, for example, how it works in World of Warcraft, where you could reach, say, 85% crit, but only crit 60% of time time because of Glancing Blows. There is no evidence that D3 works in this way, but your evidence doesn't disprove it.

Comment: 100% critical chance means that you get a crit each shot? Aren't critical displayed in yellow?

Answer (score 1):

The game DOES cap at 100% with the DH passive, they will ALWAYS ALWAYS crit for 1 second. (I suggest spamming very hard hitting spells here)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just to mention your 100% critical chance is raised because of a passive skill which just raises your chance for a critical hit to 100% it don't mather if you have 40% or just 10% after 30 seconds you have max critical chance which is 100% any value more than 100% would be useless because it's a sure critical! That passive skill also provides your critical chance for the first mob you hit with the next attack! The second attack has just normal critical chance (40%, 10%, whatever) ...
I am not sure if there is a critical hit chance - cap but ima pretty sure you will never reach the 100% with gear (just like you think it is)

Comment: its possible to reach perma 100% crit as a barb with gear + passives + skills