# What is the highest critical chance and critical damage that is possible through items alone?

Tags: diablo-iii

Is it possible to get 100% critical chance through items and how high can my critical damage get?

Please explain the gear needed.
i.e. Bow with 100% critical damage with socket 100% critical damage = 200% critical damage

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Critical Strike chance have a cap?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67160/does-critical-strike-chance-have-a-cap)

Comment: I believe limiting this by excluding 1 skill does not make it distinct enough.  Now if you limited the scope to include **only** items, I think that would be acceptable.

Comment: updated to be more specific

Comment: When you say "how high can my critical damage get", are you really talking about how much of a bonus % to critical damage you can get?  As opposed to what the actual damage would be, which would depend on everything else that affects your damage as well.

Comment: yes, just the critical damage %

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here is a list with max values for each slot of Critical Hit Chance / Critical Hit Damage

- Max per gearset: 54% / 450%
- ## gear slots: 7 / 5
- Weapn: 0% / 100% + (100% gem)
- Offhnd: 10% / 0%
- Shield: 10% / 0%
- Amulet: 10% / 65%
- Ring: 6% / 35%
- Belt: 0% / 0%
- Boots: 0% / 0%
- Bracer: 6% / 0%
- Chest: 0% / 0%
- Gloves: 10% / 50%
- Helm: 6% / 0%
- Pants: 1% / 0%
- Shldr: 0% / 0%
- Cloak: 0% / 0%
- Mighty Belt: 0% / 0%
- Spirit Stone: 6% / 0%
- Voodoo Mask: 6% / 0%
- Wizard hat: 6% / 0%

As you can see the Max per gear set is: 55% for Critical Hit Chance and 450% for Critical Hit Damage, this does not include legendary or set items, that could increase these values even further.

Even with skills like + 10% from Archery and + 2*6% Demon Hunter Skill Bonus: Multishot (+Crit) you will only have 64%. It should not be possible to reach 100% Critical Hit Chance with any gear.

Edit: Actually you could go for 2 weapons instead of one and so you can get 650% (another 100% + 100% socket) Critical Hit Damage.

I made a rough estimate what your maximum DPS could be:

Assuming you have a 1500 DPS weapon with a socket, 3008 Main Attribute (DEX) and 1,9 APS (with best modification), 54% Critical Hit Chance and 450% Critical Hit Damage you will get about 380k DPS. Assuming you have even more damage modifications like +20% more damage from certain skills / passives will allow you to output about 460k+ DPS.

[Source](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/item-affix-quick-look-chart)

Demon Hunters can gain an extra 7% from the two item bonus of [Natalya's Wrath](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-shadow-2Ggc9T).  The only legendary that provides a crit bonus in a non-standard slot is [Inna's Glory](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-glory-Z7v47), providing 1% in the pants slot.

Wanderlust (ring) + spirit of adventure (amulet) gives set bonus: endless journey, which gives +50% critical hit damage?

Comment: Diablo has 7m HP for each phase. You would have to hit him for about 15 seconds in each phase. Even less with +% damage from your skills.

Comment: Inna's Glory (pants) provides +1% Crit Chance.  It is the only legendary/set that has this stat for a non-standard slot.

Comment: A legendary Chest "The Inquisitor" and "Beckon Sail" also provide a 1% critical hit chance.

Comment: The Inquisitor and Beckon Sail are "Demon Hunter" only, as they are cloaks. Also, don't forget, the Scoundrel follower has a skill that will increase your Crit Hit chance by another 3%

Comment: The legendary item [Sever](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/sever) has a 1% crit chance, but only 1 random property, which might roll as crit damage or gem slot, both of which result in max. 100% crit damage.

Answer (score 4):

Crit *Chance* on Gear: **54%** - **59.5%**
Crit *Damage* on Gear: **385%** - **604%**

Crit chance and damage from gear depends on class due to class-specific legendary items, and the ability of some classes to dual-weild.

Also, note that you cannot achieve both maximum crit chance, AND crit damage at the same time, because max chance requires a shield, and max crit damage requires dual-weilding.  Classes without dual-weilding can achieve their personal maximum in both.

Demon Hunters have the best all-around crit gear opportunities, with the highest crit-chance, and a tie for the 2nd best crit damage.

Barbarians have the best crit damage, and the 2nd best crit chance.

Monks tie for 2nd in crit damage opportunities, and tie for last in crit chance.

Witch Doctors and Wizards have the worst opportunities for crit gear.

### Chance to Crit

Max Crit Chance From non-legendary gear: 49.5%

- Amulet: 8.5%
- Ring: 4.5% (x2)
- Bracer: 6%
- Gloves: 10%
- Helm: 6%
- Shield: 10%

Non-Shield Off-Hands can go up to 8.5%.  Class-Specific Helms can go up to 4.5%

Crit Chance above slot-max from Legendaries and Set Items:

- Set: [Natalya's Wrath](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-soul)(2 - piece): 7% (Boots + Ring/Helm for non-DH)

  - Non DH only get 2.5 more by getting this set, since they lose a 4.5% ring.
- Pants: [Inna's Glory](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/innas-glory): 1%
- Chest: [Beckon Sail](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/beckon-sail): 1% (Demon Hunter Only)
- Off-Hand: [Black Bone Arrows](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/black-bone-arrows): 7.5% (Demon Hunter Only)
- Waist: 1%

  - [Lamentation](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/lamentation): (Barbarian Only)
  - [Pride of Cassius](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/pride-of-cassius): (Barbarian Only)
- 1H Weapon: 1%

  - [Flesh Tearer](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/flesh-tearer)
  - [Kill](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/kill)
  - [Nutcracker](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/nutcracker)
  - [Arreat's Law](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/arreats-law)
  - [Sever](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/sever)
  - [Born's Seething Rage](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/borns-seething-rage)
  - [Shenlong's Crashing Tide](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/shenlongs-crashing-tide) (Monk Only)
  - [Natalya's Redemption](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/natalyas-redemption) (Demon Hunter Only)

Crit Chance By Class (Gear-only, including legendary/set):

- Barbarian: 55%
- Demon Hunter: 59.5% (57% with Black Bone Arrows instead of a shield).
- Monk: 54%
- Witch Doctor: 54%
- Wizard: 54%

### Bonus Crit Damage

Max Crit Damage Bonus from non-legendary gear: 585%

- Amulet: 65%
- Ring: 35% (x2)
- Gloves: 50%
- Weapon: 100% (x2)
- Weapon Socket: 100% (x2)

Crit Damage above slot-max from Legendaries and Set Items:

- Waist:

  - [Pride of Cassius](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/pride-of-cassius): 19% (Barbarian Only)
  - [Witching Hour](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/the-witching-hour) 12% (Barbarian Only)

Crit Damage By Class (Gear-only, including legendary/set):

- Barbarian: 604%
- Demon Hunter: 585%
- Monk: 585%
- Witch Doctor: 385%
- Wizard:  385%

Only Barbarians can use the Legendary Mighty Belts, and Witch Doctors and Wizard's can't Dual-Weild, preventing them from getting a 2nd weapon and weapon-gem.

[Source](http://www.d3rmt.com/guides/diablo-3-item-stat-maximum-values/)

I verified this source by doing scans of the Auction House.  For example, I was able to find a large number of 8.5% crit-chance Amulets.  I was not able to find ANY amulets with more than 8.5% crit-chance.  I did this search without selecting a specific character (to avoid level band restrictions), and on both the Gold and Real-Money Auction House.

In all cases, the crit chance numbers they claimed were available were found in high numbers, and anything larger than that was non-existent.  Please post a comment if you see an item that exceeds these ranges.

Also, these numbers reflect patch 1.0.3.  The [preview article for 1.0.4](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6923456/104_Systems_Preview-8_10_2012) suggests that 2-Handed Weapons will be getting new stat-budgets, which may change these ranges.  It also mentions new Legendary Items, which may include off-slot bonuses not mentioned here.

Comment: Edit amulet 10% CC now... Considering skills Barbarians Can have 10% CC from Berserker + 3%CC and 15%CDmg from Battle rage + passiv Weaponmaster when they use axes/maces + 10% CC   + ruthless 5% CC and 50% CDmg ===> Barbarian +28%CC and + 65%CDmg ===> With a shield  = 84,5%CC or Dual W =74.5%CC// 669% CDmg ;-) Yeah Yeah Far-fetched :-p