# How much is one point of each affix worth for damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

Now that the Mystic has graced us with her presence, we can change a single affix on items.  Trouble is, it's sometimes really hard to figure out how much each point is worth.  Should I replace Attack Speed?  Maybe my main stat?  The only way to know currently is to replace it, and see how the damage changes.  That's not at all optimal.

I know [Crit Damage and Crit Chance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75882/optimal-ratio-for-crit-chance-dmg) synergize, and Attack Speed kind of dumps itself on top of that as well, so a formula to calculate that would be very useful.

I'm not looking for those affixes that add elemental damage, or damage to a specific skill; those are a straight percentage increase to damage.  Just the ones that make up your damage stat on your character screen.  I'm aware it's not really possible to calculate true DPS in anything approaching reasonableness.

For any item type, what affixes contribute to damage, and how much would a single point add to damage?

Comment: Why was this thumbed down? o_e

Comment: This just sounds like a super complicated way to ask, "What is the formula for damage?"

Comment: +Damage affix contributes one point of damage per point!

Comment: @OrcJMR Wrong, because when you already have +10% arcane damage for example. Adding 1% arcane damage only effectively adds 0.9% damage.

Comment: @Divinicus That was a joke. Of course this is not one-to-one, if only because the question is actually about DPS, not average damage per attack.

Comment: @Divinicus But in that context, I'm still right - one point of damage bonus adds one **point** of average damage to an attack, not **percent**.

Answer (score 5):

The (advanced) formula to calculate damage is this:

**DMG = (AWD x (WS + AS / 100 x WS) x PS / 100 x CC / 100 x (CHD + 100) / 100) + (AWD x (WS + AS / 100 x WS) x PS / 100 x (1 - CC / 100))**

DMG = Damage you will do

AWD = Average Weapon Damage (don't forget to include your offhand and other items with + average damage)

AS = Attack speed Increase as it is in the Details Tab (10% attack speed = insert 10 into formula)

WS = default Weapon speed

PS = Primary stat (Int for WD and Wizard, ...)

CC = Crit chance (10% crit chance = insert 10 into formula)

CHD = Crit Hit Damage (100% crit hit damage = insert 100 into formula)

actually i just copied my answer to this post:

[formula for calculating damage](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165804/enchant-property-damage-vs-attack-speed)

Comment: So how does one point in any stat affect damage?

Comment: It depends on how much you got in the other stats, just fill in your stats in the formula and change the ones you want to know about.

Comment: That's the whole point of this question.  I wasn't looking for the complete damage formula; I was looking for how any single point affects damage.

Comment: @frank that depends entirely on your gear

Comment: @z- But can be calculated, probably quite well, by assuming static values for all but one.

Comment: This may be possible for some of them, but for others, the increase in damage per point relies on other stats (see CC/CHD)

Comment: @Frank The only way to compare is to run this full calculation before and after your one point increase, because the effectiveness of increasing one stat is always based on all your stats.

Answer (score 3):

Go there : http://www.diabloprogress.com/rating.stat_dps_unbuffed

Enter your character then look at the sheet.
At bottom you have some DPS calculator, it doesn't take everything into account, but it does tell you how much each point is worth for the most common stats:

Like, for my character, something like that :

- 1.00% +Arcane Skills Damage gives you 7,658.07 dps
- 1.00% Critical Hit Chance gives you 13,988.38 dps
- 1.00% Critical Damage gives you 2,118.24 dps
- 1.00% Attack Speed gives you 8,644.34 dps
- 100 Intelligence gives you 13,424.15 dps

I believe that's what you are searching for, am I right?

Comment: Very close, indeed.  It would be better if it *did* have every affix, but for the moment, this is the better answer.